# PHP Factory Pattern : Should I use `create()` or `__invoke()`?

Tags: php, comparative-review, factory-method

I currently had a colleague reviewing my code and he had a comment on a factory class I created. It's very simple:

```
class ResponseFactory
{
    public function create(array $curlInfo, array $rawResponse): ResponseInterface
    {
        return new Response($curlInfo, $rawResponse);
    }
}

$responseFactory = new ResponseFactory();
$response = $responseFactory->create(...);
```

His comment was that I should use the `__invoke()`-method of PHP. In that case, the code would look like this:

```
class ResponseFactory
{
    public function __invoke(array $curlInfo, array $rawResponse): ResponseInterface
    {
        return new Response($curlInfo, $rawResponse);
    }
}

$responseFactory = new ResponseFactory();
$response = $responseFactory(...);
```

Now I am wondering: is this just a matter of taste? Or is there real benefit in using `__invoke()` over a public `create()`-method?

Any thoughts or insights on this matter are more than welcome. I'm really trying to find good use cases for the `__invoke()`-method, but I'm not sure if a factory is one of them.

Comment: I'd consider not using factory at all in this case, because it doesn't solve any problem. Hard to see any abstraction in it either, because `Response` and factory parameters look too specific. If at least one of them would be factory's property then it would make more sense. Now it looks like either class that is calling the factory or some part of it should be factory itself.

Answer (score 3):

The only benefit of using `__invoke()` is that you can store the instance of the class in a variable as a callback and then use it without `call_user_func_array()`. But in my opinion using `create()` is more readable so you can guess easily what is the code doing.

Answer (score 2):

I choose `__invoke()` here for two reasons:

1. The existence of `__invoke()` denotes the "primary purpose" of the object. It is designed to do a single thing only, so `__invoke()` stands out from other public methods when reading the method list of the class as its primary purpose.
2. The use of `__invoke()` allows the object to be directly used as callable, without using the more cumbersome `[$object, 'create']` notation. This is analogous to the concept of "functors" in C++. Specifically, if a callable is to be passed, but you also want to pre-fill some "state" with it, you can either generate a closure or use a class with `__invoke()` method. However, in PHP, a class can offer the additional benefit of interfaces so you can implement type-safe callable which isn't possible with traditional closures. [This can be used to migrate legacy code to type-safe PHP 7 code.](https://miklcct.com/wordpress/2018/11/15/type-safe-callables-in-php-by-interfaces-with-__invoke/)